# Dynamic Memory Allocation for Pointers inside Struct

Tags: c, memory, struct, memory-management, allocation

A question with the same title has been asked before on Stack Overflow but it isn't the answer I am a looking for.

I am trying to create a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array containing the pixel data.

This is how I try doing it.

```
struct Image {
int width;
int height;
int* pixels = malloc((width * height) * sizeof(int));
};
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLldi.png)

But I am getting an error expected a ';'

The same code outside the struct works fine.

Can someone please explain to me why this errror occurs.

Comment: You need to declare the struct type in one place (global scope), and initialize an instance of that type in another place (typically function scope).

Comment: Don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text.

Comment: When you *define* a type, (i.e this struct), you may not use dynamic memory allocation. You are only permitted to use static memory, e.g: `int pixels[255]` for a fixed size buffer. Should you want to use dynamic memory, you must only declare it as a pointer, then assign the address of the dynamically allocated memory to the field at runtime.

Comment: You may want to define a constructor for the struct, which would take width and height as arguments and would do the malloc.

Comment: @MarkLavin a "constructor"? In C?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I hallucinated the "++".

Comment: @Micrified _"Should you want to use dynamic memory, you must only declare it as a pointer, then assign the address of the dynamically allocated memory to the field at runtime"_: that's somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Elaborate

Comment: @Micrified `struct Image foo; ... foo.pixels = malloc(...)`: `foo` is not a pointer here.

Comment: @Micrified So I should just declare it as a int * pixels; and then during runtime i can use malloc to allocate memory?

Comment: @Jabberwocky IDK it makes sense to me? You're assigning an address, pointing to dynamically allocated memory, to the field containing a pointer to `int *` (`foo.pixels`).

Comment: structs are type declarations, not variable declarations. Declare the struct first, declare an instance of it later - optionally with initializers.

Comment: Also why would you ever store a pixel inside a signed `int`? What color format are you using?

Comment: Eh I see. I forgot to mention he needs to declare it too. My bad yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The same code outside the struct works fine.
>
> Can someone please explain to me why this errror occurs.

This is because a `struct` in C is something different than a `struct` C#:

In C you cannot assign "default" values to struct members like this:

```
struct myStruct {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 4;
};
```

You can only assign initial **constant** values to a **variable** that has a `struct` type:

```
struct mystruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct mystruct myvar = { 5, 6 }; /* myvar.a=5, myvar.b=6 */
```

... but because `malloc()` is a function call, the following line is also not possible in C:

```
struct Image myVariable = { 10, 20, malloc(200) };
```

You **must** initialize the field `pixels` "outside the `struct`".